# creating a scatter plot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a `plot` in Python with dates as my x-axis (12/6/2010 format). [Picture is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIC2n.png).

The code I wrote is attached. I am getting an error. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\pc237\.spyder-py3\monthly_csv.csv")

df_1 = df1.loc[df1['Source'] == 'GCAG']
df_2 = df1.loc[df1['Source'] == 'GISTEMP']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = df_1['Date'],
y1 = df_1['Mean'],

x1 = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in x1]

plt.scatter(x1,y1)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.py", line 213, in convert
    values = tools.to_datetime(values)
```

Comment: I don't think list comprehension is needed here because your x1 is already a pandas object. Try:

    x1 = pd.to_datetime(x1)

Comment: If that doesn't work, show more of the traceback'

Comment: Traceback:File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 428, in to_datetime
    return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 345, in _convert_listlike
    raise TypeError('arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, '
TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: i see this error also:    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/6/1880'

Comment: try also, setting infer_datetime_format=True when calling to_datetime

Answer (score 0):

I don't think list comprehension is needed here because your x1 is already a pandas object. And you need to set the infer datetime format flag to True.

```
x1 = pd.to_datetime(x1, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: Add a print out of the x1 variable to the question prompt just before your call to to_datetime. From your tracebacks, it is impossible to tell what you are trying to convert to a datetime